# Onenote Api embed OneNote Container to my website

Tags: php, onenote, onenote-api

Does anyone know if possible to embed **OneNote Container** editor on my website through API?

Comment: Yes, but I didn't find anything

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for specifically isn't possible.  But what is your scenario? There might be a way to achieve your goals.

Comment: Hi @jayongg, thanks for your response. 
My scenario is: I want to integrate OneNote container to my website, through API, and to manipulate with that, on the end I'll save data on OneNote and on my website ie. I'll save onenote_Id.